# What is an efficient way to compute cross tab in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, join, optimization

I have a table called messages with two columns: userA and userB.

Each user has a type: typeA or typeB.

I want to compute a cross tabulation of the number of messages sent between different types of users. Users can also be both typeA and typeB. Types are stored in a different table: (id:1, typeA), (id:2, typeB)

```
userA/userB | typeA | typeB
-----
typeA          2000    81348
-----
typeB         18348    12938
```

How do I do this efficiently? Suppose I have 100000 messages. If I perform the first inner join for userA: I would get in the worst case 7*100000 records. Now if I perform the second inner join for userB: I would get 7*7*100000 records. That second join query takes a very long time.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT src.type AS `UserA/UserB`, SUM(dest.type = 'typeA') AS typeA, SUM(dest.type = 'typeB') AS typeB
FROM messages AS msgsrc
JOIN users AS src ON msgsrc.userA = src.id
JOIN messages AS msgdest ON msgsrc.userA = msgdest.userB
JOIN users AS dest ON msgdest.userB = dest.id
GROUP BY `UserA/UserB`
```

If there are more types of users, just keep adding more `SUM(dest.type = 'TypeX')` columns.

If you don't need the sums in separate columns, you can do:

```
SELECT src.type AS srcType, dest.type AS destType, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM messages AS msgsrc
JOIN users AS src ON msgsrc.userA = src.id
JOIN messages AS msgdest ON msgsrc.userA = msgdest.userB
JOIN users AS dest ON msgdest.userB = dest.id
GROUP BY srcType, destType
```

This doesn't require modification to handle more types, and may be more efficient since it doesn't have to produce as large an intermediate table.

Comment: I should note that types are stored in a different table (edited op just now).

Comment: I've added joins with the `users` table to map the user ID to a type.

Comment: I will try this out but it doesn't address my performance concern which is the main thing. Joining these tables together will yield millions of rows.

Comment: Make sure you have indexes, that's the best you can do.